# iOS application for viewing a Photoshop file in real time in a device?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ios

I need some help in finding some application(iOS/system) where I can view my Photoshop file in real time on my iPOD(5th gen). I have tried Adobe Edge Inspect. Is there a better alternative?

If viewing a Photoshop file is not possible, then maybe a PNG.

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: Photoshop Touch maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSD Viewer PRO. It's great for viewing native PSD files on an iOS system. They have a free version, try it, but just pay the 99 cents and buy the pro version.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/psd-viewer-pro-for-photoshop/id408723437?mt=8

Comment: Cool. It's just one of those apps you don't use that often, but when you need it, it's really handy to have.

Comment: Neither the free nor the paid for version work. I can't open anything except, sometimes, the sample. Both simply crash every time. Is it because it hasn't been updated for iOS 9? If so, is there a psd viewer that actually works? Robin Ray